# SQL return row if no result found

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, left-join

I have two tables:

```
person
id
name

car
name
person_id
```

Currently the query goes like:

```
SELECT
person.name
car.name
FROM
person, car
WHERE
person.id = car.person_id
```

Now this works fine if there is a car associated with a person. However if there isn't, then the person won't get returned. If a person has no car, I want to return a row with the text `'No Car'` in column `car.name`.

Comment: Try doing a `left join` on `Person`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select person.name, coalesce(car.name, 'no car')
from person
left outer join car on person.id = car.person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person.name, CASE WHEN car.name IS NULL THEN 'no car' ELSE car.name END 
FROM person
LEFT JOIN car ON person.id = car.person_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select person.name, ISNULL(car.name, 'no car')
from person
left join car on person.id = car.person_id
```

Comment: isnull() is an RDBMs specific function, and from the tags, whilst it looks a bit ambiguous, the OP included psql - so I am taking it to mean postgres - even though its the wrong tag for that.

Comment: you are right, I just use MSSQL and wrote the query without thinking about that.