# SQL Server Query return "No data" in a row if no data found

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My code able to retrieve book code data that match with the barcode but not when there is no data match. I want it to print "no data" in the cell also if there's no data found. I did follow this but not working [SQL return row if no result found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647221/sql-return-row-if-no-result-found)

I did try this query but still, there is "no data" return row

```
 WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY InvtID Asc) rid 
  FROM InventoryCustomer) 

 SELECT InvtID
       ,coalesce(InvtID, 'bookcode not found') 
 FROM cte 
 WHERE rid=1 
  and Barcode In ("<barcode_value>")
```

Code as below,

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server="))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(null, conn))
            {
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("WITH cte AS(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY InvtID Asc) rid FROM InventoryCustomer) SELECT InvtID AS BOOKCODE FROM cte WHERE rid=1 and Barcode In (");
               for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i != 0) sb.Append(","); 

                    string name = "@P" + i; 

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, dt.Rows[i]["3"]); 
                    sb.Append(name); 
                } 
                sb.Append(") ORDER BY Barcode");

                cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);

                dt.Columns["BOOKCODE"].SetOrdinal(0);
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            }
```

}

UPDATED

I tried one-by-one barcode in sql server. As you can see in this pic [image: pic1]

when only 1 parameter the query able to print 'bookcode not found' but the 2nd pic [image: pic2]

the query only print the bookcode and not include 'bookcode not found'. Please help me to figure out how to fix this

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY InvtID Asc) rid 
FROM [dbo].[InventoryCustomer] WHERE Barcode In ('123','9789830093826') ) 
SELECT InvtID, BOOKCODE = coalesce(InvtID, 'bookcode not found') 
FROM cte WHERE rid=1 UNION SELECT InvtID = '', BOOKCODE = 'bookcode not found' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM CTE )
```

11 Feb

These are all the queries I have tried but none of it will display 'no data' if no rows are found in sql

```
1. 'SELECT isnull((SELECT InvtID 
FROM InventoryCustomer WHERE Barcode IN('123','9789830093819')),'No bookcode found') 
AS InvtID '

2. 'Select case when s.InvtID IS NOT NULL Then s.InvtID else 'no data' end as Bookcode
from (Select InvtID as InvtID FROM InventoryCustomer WHERE Barcode IN('123','9789830093819')) R
Left Join InventoryCustomer s ON s.InvtID = R.InvtID'

3. 'IF NOT EXISTS (Select InvtID From InventoryCustomer WHERE Barcode in ('123','9789830093819')) 
Begin SELECT 'Bookcode not found' as Bookcode end
ELSE
SELECT InvtID From InventoryCustomer WHERE Barcode in ('123','9789830093819')'

4. 'SELECT InvtID, CASE WHEN InvtID is null OR InvtID='' THEN 'no data'
ELSE InvtID
END AS Bookcode
FROM InventoryCustomer WHERE Barcode in ('123','9789830093819')'

5. 'WITH cte AS(SELECT case WHEN InvtID IS NULL OR InvtID='' THEN 'No Bookcode Found' 
ELSE InvtID END AS InvtID,Barcode,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY InvtID Asc) 
rid FROM InventoryCustomer) 
SELECT InvtID AS BOOKCODE FROM cte WHERE rid=1 and Barcode In ('123','9789830093819')'
```

Comment: You need use `CASE` for this and remove `where` clause

Comment: I tried no 5 query (updated quest) using case but still couldnt retrive 'no data' and I dont get it why need to remove where clause

Answer (score 1):

You may try removing the barcode check in the `WHERE` clause (which is restricting records), and instead use a `CASE` expression with the same logic.  When you encounter a non matching record, you may display `bookcode not found`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY InvtID Asc) rid
    FROM InventoryCustomer
)

SELECT
    InvtID,
    CASE WHEN Barcode IN (...) THEN InvtId ELSE 'bookcode not found' END AS status
FROM cte
WHERE rid = 1;
```

If `InvtId` is not a text column, then you may have to cast it to text as follows to make the `CASE` expression work:

```
CASE WHEN Barcode IN (...)
    THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), InvtId) ELSE 'bookcode not found' END
```

Comment: It retrieve all the invtID in database and add another new column "status" with full of 'bookcode not found'. Why is that happening

Comment: You are complaining about missing rows and I have given you a workaround. If you want something else, then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

as per your Code, if there are no matching Rows found for the Barcode, then there will be no records returned so, Just add a Dummy select to return one row if there are no matching rows

Try with this

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY InvtID Asc) rid 
    FROM InventoryCustomer
        WHERE Barcode In ("<barcode_value>")
) 
SELECT 
    InvtID, 
    MyMessage = coalesce(InvtID, 'bookcode not found') 
    FROM cte 
        WHERE rid=1 

UNION
SELECT  
    InvtID = NULL,
    MyMessage = 'bookcode not found'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM CTE 
    )
```

Comment: I tried this but still not working and why it add new "MyMessage" column?

Comment: I just gave a dummy alias Name, you can change the "MyMessage" into anything else as you wish

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please help me with it